# Datatables radio button keeps getting unchecked when going to another page (DataTables pagination)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatables

As the title suggests, it's happening to my data table. I'm not using server side paging.

Here's how I render my radio button:

```
var columns = [
  {
    "render": function (data, type, full, meta) {
      return '<input class="dtRadioBtn" type="radio" value="wibble" name="wibble"/>';
    }
  }
];
```

Here's my datatable init:

```
table = $('#table').DataTable({
    "data": data,
    "columns": columns,
    "ordering": false,
    "lengthMenu": [[3, 5, 10, -1], [3, 5, 10, "All"]],
    scrollX: "100%",
    scrollCollapse: true,
    paging: true,
    fixedColumns: {
        leftColumns: 3,
        heightMatch: 'none'
    }
});
```

A checked radio button gets unchecked when I go to another page.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: you can build your logic like store `, comma` seprated value in one variable and on page change populate data from that variable.

Comment: im sorry, i dont get what you're saying. can you please elaborate more?

Comment: Could you please post the rest of your code, how you are loading `data` variable, when do you call DataTable initialization ?  I can only suspect that you are initializing DataTable again and again when changing the page. Could you setup something like a demo example so the people can realize your problem better ?

Comment: Please refer this [good documentation](https://www.gyrocode.com/articles/jquery-datatables-checkboxes/) about check boxes in datatable, you can get idea and do for radio.